# While mounted on a horse, do you really miss events & encounters?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I read that if you're riding your horse around, random events/encounters either do not happen or certain types never happen (or events happen less).

Is this true? Or is it the exact same as walking around?

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mirsj/i_have_but_1_complaint_after_40_hours_of_playing/c318vv5

> You are immune to the random encounters on the roads like thugs/bandits stopping you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't use my horse all that often but when I have I've had random events happen. IE and assassin tries to kill me or I find a group of thieves waiting to ambush me.

Comment: Correct, random events still happen.

Comment: However, triggered events, such as a thief actually waiting for you or you trying to enter Winterhold are indeed skipped, which is annoying but harmless, so far.